# How can I add yotpo review in static block in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, blocks

I want to get yotpo review in my static block and want to show it on the front end.
I want to inherit a review like this code.

{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" template="Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml"}}

but I don't have any idea how I can get it

Comment: Please use - https://support.yotpo.com/en/article/setting-up-yotpo-on-magento-v22-and-above

Comment: @ZealousWeb ok thank you