# How to add tab for login and registration form in magento?

Tags: magento2, registration

I want to show the login and registration  form in a tab , when I click registration form should be open, and when I click login form login for should be open

Comment: you need designer help to show the login and registration tab separately. check below link https://codepen.io/MatthewBryce/pen/gwdkky

Comment: https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/bootstrap-login-63670890

Comment: @Devidas okay bro thanks

Comment: don't post the same question repeated. you can edit and update same question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/345091/how-to-create-tab-structure-for-login-registration-page-in-magento2

Comment: @Devidas ok bro i deleted that question

Comment: Do you want any help?

Comment: You will still need a help of designer to make design proper. I will just show the tabbing section

Comment: You need to design everything with the help of designer

Comment: @ZealousWeb okay thanks

Comment: Please check added answer and change your css according to your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the below code in your theme files. I have shown you here that how we can set tabbing section.

Also written here is some piece of code CSS. Please change CSS according to your need.

Please add js code in your script.js file. Here I have added code in the phtml file but please write CSS and js in proper theme files.

> Step 1:- Please create file customer_account_login.xml under path
> app/design/frontend/{{YOUR THEME NAME HERE}}/{{YOUR THEME PACKAGE NAME
> HERE}}/Magento_Customer/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Customer Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="timber.login.register.section" template="Magento_Customer::form/both.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="customer_form_login" template="Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml" cacheable="false">
                    <container name="messages.view.new" as="messages_new_view"/>
                    <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="loginButton" xsi:type="string">.action.login</item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="Magento_Customer::form/register.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="attribute_data" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Block\DataProviders\AddressAttributeData</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                    <container name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="customer-form-before"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="registerSubmitButton" xsi:type="string">.action.submit</item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="form_additional_info_customer" template="Magento_Customer::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Step 2:- Please create file both.phtml under path
> app/design/frontend/{{YOUR THEME NAME HERE}}/{{YOUR THEME PACKAGE NAME
> HERE}}/Magento_Customer/templates/form/

```
<div class="login-container">
    <ul class="tabs-menu customer-tabs-menu">
        <li>    
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-tab="tab-1" class="login-title current">
                <strong id="block-customer-login-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Log in')) ?></strong>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-tab="tab-2" class="login-title">
                <strong id="block-customer-register-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Create an account')) ?></strong>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab">
        <div id="tab-1" class="timber-login tab-content current"> 
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('customer_form_login'); ?>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-2" class="timber-register tab-content" style="display: none;">
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('customer_form_register'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery',"mage/url"],function($,url){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('ul.customer-tabs-menu li a').click(function(){
                $('.tab-content').hide();
                var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
                $('ul.tabs-menu li a').removeClass('current');
                $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
                $(this).addClass('current');
                $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
                $("#"+tab_id).show();
            })
        });
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.login-container {
    background: #ffffff;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 40px auto;
}
.tabs-menu li {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.login-container .login-title.current {
    background: #e8e7e7;
    color: #010101;
}
.login-container .login-title strong {
    font-family: "Arkibal Display";
    font-weight: 400;
}
.login-container .login-title {
    background: #666568;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.tab-content.current {
    clear: both;
}
.block-customer-login, .form-create-account {
    max-width: 450px !important;
    margin: auto !important;
    padding: 50px 15px !important;
}
.timber-login {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
}
</style>
```

I have done in luma theme.

Please check the output:-

https://prnt.sc/1qhkjgg
https://prnt.sc/1qhkjs0

**Cheers!**

Comment: Hey thanks but its not working in my custom theme

Comment: How you trying?

Comment: Show me your code

Comment: I implement all code as your instruction but i did not found anything . I created  app/design/frontend/Myshop/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/customer_account_login.xml and paste your code , I also created /app/design/frontend/Myshop/theme/Magento_Theme/templates/form/both.phtml file and paste your code but i did not found result

Comment: I have written to create file under Magento_Customer. And you have created file under path Magento_Theme. Please read answer properly and implement.

Comment: Okay sorry i  check it

Comment: After create files under Magento_Customer , please check your output here - http://yourdomain.com/customer/account/login/

Comment: Thank you so much now its working  for me

Comment: Hey please see my this question if you have any idea related this help me please https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/345061/how-can-i-add-yotpo-review-in-static-block-in-magento2

Comment: How can I add yotpo review in static block in Magento2?

Comment: @ZealousWeb, does the same work for Magento 2.4.6 ?